# react native tab reset on leave of tab

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am working on react native tabbed application using react navigation.

I have 2 tabs, `HomeScreen` and `SettingsScreen` and a DetailsScreen.

On tab HomeScreen, I have

1. Button
2. When user will click on the button it will take to details screen.

Now if a user from the bottom tab clicks on `SettingsScreen` tab and return back to `HomeScreen` tab, screen `DetailsScreen` is still active.

Here is code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator,
    createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Home!</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Go to Details"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}


class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Details!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}



class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Settings!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Settings: SettingsScreen
});


export default createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeStack,
        Settings: SettingsStack,
    }
);
```

How can make in the way that when the user returns from tab `SettingsScreen` to `HomeScreen`, they will see HomeScreen with the button rather than  `DetailsScreen`.